Why does the model trained on Apple gpu performs worse than when it is trained on Apple cpu (M2)?
A simple CNN model was trained on Apple CPU and on Apple GPU, and both model performances were evaluated on the test data set; the one trained on Apple CPU had an accuracy of 98%, while the one trained on GPU had an accuracy of 10%.
Both models are the same, and below is the code used to train and test the model. PyTorch was used to create the model.
CPU
for epoch in trange(3):  
    for images, labels in tqdm(train_loader):
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
       
        x = images  
        y = model(x)
        loss = criterion(y, labels)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step() #Updating the weights

GPU
for epoch in trange(3):  
    for images, labels in tqdm(train_loader):
        images, labels = images.to(device).float(), labels.to(device).float() 
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
        x = images  
        y = model_gpu(x).to(device)
        loss = criterion(y, labels)
        
      
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

Model testing
GPU
m = model_gpu.to("cpu") #transferring the model to cpu

correct = 0
total = len(mnist_test)

with torch.no_grad():
    for images, labels in tqdm(test_loader):
        images, labels = images, labels
      
        x = images  
        y = m(x)

        predictions = torch.argmax(y, dim=1)
        correct += torch.sum((predictions == labels).float())

print('Test accuracy: {}'.format(correct/total)) 

Also tried testing it on the GPU but the results were same.
CPU
correct = 0
total = len(mnist_test)

with torch.no_grad():
    for images, labels in tqdm(test_loader):
        # Forward pass
        x = images  
        y = model(x)

        predictions = torch.argmax(y, dim=1)
        correct += torch.sum((predictions == labels).float())

print(f'Test accuracy: ',{correct/total})


This is a code smell that you have duplicated code for the CPU training and GPU training. Refactor your code so the data loading, model instantiation, training and testing have the exact same code. Then, before all this code, set a variable device that set the device cpu or cuda. Then perform your training/testing again. If the difference is still there, maybe the GPU has a bigger batch_size than the CPU. You should scale the learning rate according to the batch size, see this paper. Otherwise, watch out for other hyperparameters variations.
